# Translation of UML aggregation into a relational model

Tags: uml, relational-database, aggregation

```
(Class A)                       (Class C)
 [0..1]__________________________[1..*]
                  |
                  |
                  |
              (Class B)
```

How do I convert this into a relational model? I am basically looking for creating these 3 tables in SQL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Object-relational mapping (ORM) is a technique for mapping between object-oriented systems and relational databases". You can find many Stack Overflow questions under tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orm, probably best way to start would be: select the implementation language, find the most popular ORM framework for your language, read the framework's tutorials..

Comment: 1. what do you mean by this B class? Slashed line normally means "is based on" link and connects type to type, not type to relationship. 2. No arrows standardly mean both-side connection, is it OK?